# com.cybersource.ws.client.ClientException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ssl-certificate

I'm very new to SSL so please bare if I have asked any dumb question.

I'm developing a Java EE web application which deals with credit card transactions. Here I'm trying to use a p12 certificate from cybersource.

I have a local, dev environment which runs in Windows and I use tomcat a my app server. Everything works fine in my local environment. When I move the same application to a Unix/Websphere environment I'm getting, "com.cybersource.ws.client.ClientException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found" even after giving the right certificate path in the UNIX box.

I consulted with my UNIX admin team for this issue, and they asked me to convert p12 file to JKS and place in the WEB_INF/Classes folder. I have done it using keytool and converted the p12 cert to JKS. Still my WebSphere could not recognize the certificate location.

How is the type of file related here? Why can't I use the p12 file instead of JKS. My UNIX team says, I have to deal something with my code. I'm stuck with this issue since a week.

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere manages the files for you.

You need to add the signer certificate to the trust store. Is really simple, just follow IBM documentation:

1. Log into the WebSphere console (usually https://:9043/ibm/console)
   Click on Security > SSL Certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates.
2. List item
3. Click CellDefaultTrustStore.
4. Click Signer Certificates.
5. Click Retrieve from port.
   Enter the Host name, SSL Port, and Alias of the web server. The Alias is typically an arbitrary string that will become the name of the credentials.
   Click Retrieve Signer Information and then click OK. The root certificate is added to the list of signer certificates.
6. Restart your WebSphere server and try again with your app, if it still fails you should be aware of importing signer certificates and not just the signed certificates.

Hope this helps